# How to run upgrade script manually (1.9.0.0 to 1.9.1.0)

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0, upgrade

I'm currently experiencing some urgent problems with my Magento website.

I have upgraded my website from 1.9.0.0 to 1.9.1.0 and now it seems like the upgrade script (database) do not run entirely.

```
Table 'website.core_email_queue' doesn't exist' in /home/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
```

Some settings are also missing in the core_config_data tables... Is it possible to rerun the upgrade scripts manually because currently I can't find where...

Some people suggest to modify the version in core_ressources but I don't think it's the best solution. I have triend to reinstall Mage_Core_Modules and Mage_Core_Adminhtml from the downloader but it doesn't seem to work.

I also have tried to redownload the core files of Magento and override core file in my setup, but it doesn't work at all. I can't get the missing tables created.

Thanks !

Comment: I would guess that the re-downloaded files won't make any difference, if you're pointing at the database, due to the reference in core_resource.  it reads this version number first before looking for files to apply patches for.  if it's already higher, it wont install the patches again.

Comment: Looks like you have a module, which create a core_email_queue table. Try to reinstall it.

Answer (score 10):

You can solved the problem by downgrading the version number in the table `core_resource`, as already written.

Alternatively, you can use tools like [n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) to trigger all install scripts

```
n98-magerun.phar sys:setup:run
```

It has always solved my problems.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem by downgrading the version number in the table `core_resource`.

Don't know if it's the best way to proceed, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem with the `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly` table after upgrade from 1.9.1 to 1.9.3.  It was on my beta server and I realized that some upgrade scripts didn't run because I forgot to reset file permissions after pulling the new files down from github.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/magento/.
```

did the trick for me.